# Negative uid in android 10 (Android q) batterystat

Tags: android, adb, uid

After do `adb shell dumpsys batterystats`, I got a strange entity show below, I can't find which application it is related to. Can someone help me figure out?

```
Estimated power use (mAh):
  Uid -5: 54.6 ( radio=54.6 ) Including smearing: 71.1 ( proportional=16.5 )

Per-app mobile ms per packet:
  Uid -5: 177 (13586 packets over 40m 3s 997ms) 60x

-5:
    Mobile network: 35.78MB received, 2.48MB sent (packets 5662 received, 7924 sent)
    Mobile radio active: 40m 3s 997ms (18.0%) 60x @ 177 mspp
       Cellular Sleep time:  0ms (0.0%)
       Cellular Idle time:   0ms (0.0%)
       Cellular Rx time:     11m 33s 419ms (1.7%)
       Cellular Tx time:     
         less than 0dBm:  3m 15s 498ms (0.5%)
         0dBm to 8dBm:  10s 867ms (0.0%)
         8dBm to 15dBm:  12m 52s 610ms (1.9%)
         15dBm to 20dBm:  10m 44s 566ms (1.6%)
         above 20dBm:  9s 112ms (0.0%)
    (nothing executed)
```

And there are nothing else related to "-5" in this batterystats file.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fingure out it was the hotspot function, if don't use Hotspot, the uid will never appear in batterystat.